# Rails: authorizing user with CanCan gem issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan

I have an action in my controller that looks like the following:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    # ... more stuff.
  end
```

Note, I'm overriding the loading of the resource as CanCan tries to load with `params[:id]` and I need to use `params[:user_id]` here.

The top of my controller has the following defined:

```
  authorize_resource :only => [:show]
```

And in Ability.rb:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    can :show, User if :id == user.id
  end
end
```

All of my invocations are unauthorized however. I'm using devise for authentication and I'm verifying that the `user` object being passed into initialize is indeed the logged in user. How do I verify that the logged in `user` is only able to view the profile for which they are requesting and no other profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not overriding the loading of the resource as this is taking place before the action:

```
authorize_resource :only => [:show]
```

Instead you need to remove it and add the authorisation to your action or a separate before_filter.

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  authorize! :show, @user
```